# Are there any open source image resize and uploader for a web application?

Tags: java, javascript, html, flash, open-source

I would like look for an open source image resize and uploader for a web application. Preferably leveraging on W3C speficication and try avoid need client to install any application.

Target uploading images are limited to 1 ~ 3 and resizing in terms of width & height only.

Hopefully works well with Java technology.

Answer (score 1):

Use any upload framework and resize the images on the server using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is your friend.